# Change ItemTemplate RelativeLayout background color based on a model property with MvvmCross

Tags: android, xamarin.android, android-relativelayout, mvvmcross

I have a main view with a MvxBindableListView.
Item template has a RelativeLayout as container with TextViews, ImageView etc.. inside.

I need to be able to change background colour of the RelativeLayout based on the data is bound to the list.

Is that possible?

Comment: It's possible, yes. You'll need to do a custom binding for it though. If you intend to use the Color itself in the ViewModel then you may find the Color Plugin helpful - sorry, this is only a comment - a bit busy!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Colors can be bound to View properties fairly easily using MvxColorConverters (using the Color plugin)

For example, assuming you have a Score which goes from 1 to 10, you might color a text view according to the value:

```
public class ScoreToColorConverter : MvxBaseColorConverter
{
    private static readonly MvxColor RedColor = new MvxColor(0xff, 0x00, 0x00);
    private static readonly MvxColor GreenColor = new MvxColor(0x00, 0xff, 0x00);

    protected override MvxColor Convert(object value, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var intValue = (int)value;

        return (intValue > 5) ? RedColor : GreenColor;
    }
}
```

This converter can then be used in a View like:

```
      <TextView
          style="?OurTextViewBodyStyle"
          android:textColor="@color/red"
          local:MvxBind="{'Text':{'Path':'Score'},'TextColor':{'Path':'Status','Converter':'ScoreToColor'}}" />
```

For setting a View's Background color, you will probably need to write a small custom binding - which accesses the SetBackgroundColor() method - as the Background property itself is readonly.